# Yarn build consumes 100% CPU

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, yarnpkg, cpu-usage

I am using yarn to build several apps (mostly react-based) on the EC2 instance. During the build, the CPU usage goes up to 100% (sometimes even 135% somehow). As a result, the build process hangs forever until I kill it. At the same time, building the same apps on my local Macbook works like a charm.

My server setup is:

- Instance type: t2.small
- OS: Ubuntu 20.04.2
- Node: v16.9.0
- NPM: v7.23.0
- Yarn: 1.22.5

I tried other versions of node, npm, yarn but got the same results.

Comment: We had a similar issue. Building apps (especially in production mode) is a really expensive and memory consuming process a t2.small probably can't cut it that effectively. We have a t2.medium and it would die whenever we accidentally started a 2nd build job while another one was running

Comment: A t2.small is what - a single GB of RAM?  Sounds like it's thrashing.  Such is the nature of trying to build too much in parallel at once without enough RAM.  Although it should eventually complete unless it's a bug in the tool code.  Either way, go get a bigger instance type with more RAM memory.

Comment: So, consuming that much CPU is normal?

t2.small is 2 GB RAM, but the issue is not related to RAM - it is related to CPU. I have another prod instance running on t2.large and the CPU behavior there is the same, the only difference is that the build doesn't hang after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching to t2.medium instance type fixed the issue